# How exactly kernel reads file system from USB device and mounts it?

Tags: linux

How does usbcore reads filesystem of a usbdevice and mounts our device in /media directory. I mean how does it create block device for the device in /dev and perform operations on it. I want to know which kernel drivers are involved. I have read a lot of articles but cannot find information regarding this.